# unable to npm install youtube api search in the package.json file

Tags: npm

Please take a look at the attached. I type the following command in my terminal: npm install --save youtube-api-search in my command line (see pic) but i dont see it in the package.json file. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: --save saves in "dependencies", --save-dev saves in "devDependencies", We can't see more down hehe

Comment: Its not in dependencies...:(

Comment: this is the message i am getting in dependencies:

Comment: Sams-MacBook-Air:ReduxSimpleStarter samrao$ npm install -- save youtube-api-search
redux-simple-starter@1.0.0 /Users/samrao/Documents/ReduxSimpleStarter
├── save@2.3.1 
└── youtube-api-search@0.0.5

Comment: I did it and I see it, I don't know if you are watching the right package.json, but, it works

Comment: Thanks are you saying that the file is saving somewhere, just not the right location?

Comment: no, the package is installed under node_modules folder, but with --save flag, the package.json in the same folder in the prompt that you are executing is the package.json that should be modified, if you don't have any error, i don't know, maybe check if the package is installed under node_modules folder

Comment: its working now...thanks for all your help! i LOVE stackoverflow!!!

Answer (score 0):

the above comments enabled me to save the youtube api to devdependnecies and it showed up there, then i was also able to save it to dependencies.